# Temporary names within an expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm looking for a way to name a value within an expression to use it multiple times within that expression. Since the value is found inside the expression, I can't save it as a variable using a typical assign statement. I also want its use to be in the same function as the rest of the expression, so I would rather not break it out into a separate function.

More specifically, I enjoy comprehension. List/dictionary comprehension is my favorite Python feature. I'm trying to use both to coerce a dictionary of untrusted structure into a trusted structure (all fields exist, and their values are of the correct type). Without what I'm looking for, it would look something like this:

```
{
    ...
    'outer': [{
        ...
        'inner': {
            key: {
                ...
                'foo': {
                    'a': get_foo_from_value(value)['a'],
                    'b': get_foo_from_value(value)['b'],
                    ...
                }
            } for key, value in get_inner_from_outer(outer)
        }
    } for outer in get_outer_from_dictionary(dictionary)]
}
```

Those function calls are actually expressions, but I would like to only evaluate `get_foo_from_value(value)` once. Ideally there would be something like this:

```
'foo': {
    'a': foo['a'],
    'b': foo['b'],
    ...
} with get_foo_from_value(value) as foo
```

So far the options I've come up with are single-item generators and lambda expressions. I'm going to include an example of each as an answer so they can be discussed separately.

Comment: It would be good to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is not this sufficient: `dictionary['foo'] = foo`?

Comment: I'm trying to do the whole thing as a combination of comprehension. `dictionary` is provided, `outer` comes from a list comprehension based on a transformation of `dictionary['outer']`, `inner` comes from a dictionary comprehension based on a transformation of `outer['inner']`, and I'm looking for a way to do the transformation from `value['foo']` to `foo` only once while still being able to use it when constructing `new_dictionary['outer'][index]['inner'][key]['foo']`.

Comment: Note that Haskell has this as a first-class language feature (in both `let` and `where` forms).

Answer (score 1):

**lambda solution**

```
'foo': (lambda foo: {
    'a': foo['a'],
    'b': foo['b'],
    ...
})(get_foo_from_value(value))
```

I feel like this one isn't as readable as it could be. I also don't like creating a lambda that only gets called once. I like that the name appears before it's used, but I don't like the separation of its name and value.

Answer (score 0):

**single-item generator solution**

This is currently my favorite solution to the problem (I like comprehension, remember).

```
'foo': next({
    'a': foo['a'],
    'b': foo['b'],
    ...
} for foo in [get_foo_from_value(value)])
```

I like it because the generator expression matches the rest of the comprehension in the expression, but I'm not a huge fan of the `next` and having to wrap `get_foo_from_value(value)` in brackets.